# A more efficient aggregation than the term aggregation ?

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch, nosql, duplicates

I have 1003000 docs and most of them are duplicates. I checked with the term aggregation and saw that i have 245538 different keys( I have an id field in this table).

This aggregations took around 1 second which is great. However i needed to find the '_id' of the docs that are a duplicate. So i did an aggregation on that aggregation

```
'aggs': {
    'dupcount': {
        'terms': {
            'field': 'id',
            'min_doc_count': 2,
            'size': 300000
        },
        'aggs': {
            'dupdoc': {
                'top_hits': {
                    'size': 16
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The size of top hits is 16 because the maximum duplicates of 1 key are 16.

Unfortunately This was too heavy for the cluster itself and it shut down.

The other option is using the scan api but it takes around 20 seconds which is too much. So is there a more efficient and stable aggregation to found the duplicates in this case  ?

I am using ElasticSearch 6.3 with python, Thanks in advance.

Comment: One optimization you could make is to add `_source: false` to the top_hits aggregation since you only need the id

Comment: Still shuts down or takes too much time.

Comment: Yeah with 300K buckets, that's pretty logical. Why don't you just take less buckets (say 1000), fix them, rinse and repeat with the next 1000, etc? (divide and conquer)

Comment: The problem is that the elasticsearch is not the main DB, so i need to fix the main DB first, I dont really care how much time it takes to fix the elastic DB. if i do what you said it is better to just fix the main DB using sql or using the scan api.

Comment: If you can reimport everything easily, then it's always best to fix the primary source of data, indeed.

Comment: So in finding duplicates the elasticsearch cant help me ?

Comment: You can use ES to find duplicates and fix the DB with the results. However, what would be interesting to know is why you have dups in the first place? What does your import process do or doesn't do to prevent this?

Comment: The main DB ( the one that is not stored in ES) has many dups because it was created by merging a lot of tables together, I thought that maybe in  elasticsearch finding their id would be faster than doing it through cursors that goes through the DB.

Comment: Ok, I see, garbage in garbage out, basically :-) If you only fix ES, and at some point later for some reason you need to reimport the data from the DB, you'll end up with the same problems. Anyway, if you only want to fix ES, you definitely can with the method I explained above.

Comment: Alright thank you very much :)